# Quarkus native get the value of an annotation

Tags: java, reflection, cucumber, native, quarkus

I am trying to acces the value inside of an annotation when I compile my code to quarkus native using the command ./mvnw package `-Pnative`.
I am trying to use Cucumber cli to execute to execute my code like this: `Main.run("-g", "com.hellocucumber", "file:/hellocucumber.feature")`.
I have made some modifications to the source code to get it to work with Quarkus native compilation. My main problem is that there's this block of code `Method expressionMethod = annotation.getClass().getMethod("value");` inside of the `io.cucumber.java.GlueAdaptor` which fails with the error  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: io.cucumber.java.en.Given$$ProxyImpl.value()` because we are trying to access the value of the annotation defined in the StepDefinition class. Here is my step definition class, as well as my feature file.

```
public class StepDefinitions {
    @Given("today is Sunday")
    public void today_is_Sunday() {
        //Print a message
    }

    @When("I ask whether it's Friday yet")
    public void i_ask_whether_it_s_Friday_yet() {
        //Print a message
    }
    
    @Then("I should be told {string}")
    public void i_should_be_told(String expectedAnswer) {
        //Print a message
    }
 
 }

Scenario: Sunday isn't Friday
    Given today is Sunday
    When I ask whether it's Friday yet
    Then I should be told Nope
```

I have tried to add the annotation classes (io.cucumber.java.en.Given, io.cucumber.java.en.And, etc) to the reflect.json and provide it to the native compilation   as follows: `quarkus.native.additional-build-args=-H:DynamicProxyConfigurationResources=reflect-config.json`, this doesn't seem to work.
I have also moved all the code I modified into an extension and tried to modify the annotations like this:

```
@BuildStep
    void addProxies(CombinedIndexBuildItem combinedIndexBuildItem,
                    BuildProducer<NativeImageProxyDefinitionBuildItem> proxies) {
        proxies.produce(new NativeImageProxyDefinitionBuildItem(StepDefinitionAnnotation.class.getName()));
        proxies.produce(new NativeImageProxyDefinitionBuildItem(Given.class.getName()));
        proxies.produce(new NativeImageProxyDefinitionBuildItem(When.class.getName()));
        proxies.produce(new NativeImageProxyDefinitionBuildItem(Then.class.getName()));
        proxies.produce(new NativeImageProxyDefinitionBuildItem(And.class.getName()));
        proxies.produce(new NativeImageProxyDefinitionBuildItem(But.class.getName()));
    }
```

This didn't work either, so finally I tried this:

```
@BuildStep
void transformAnnotations(BuildProducer<AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem> transformers) {


    transformers.produce(new AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem(new AnnotationsTransformer() {
        @Override
        public boolean appliesTo(AnnotationTarget.Kind kind) {
            return kind == AnnotationTarget.Kind.METHOD;
        }

        @Override
        public void transform(TransformationContext ctx) {
            AnnotationTarget target = ctx.getTarget();
            MethodInfo methodInfo = target.asMethod();
            ClassInfo classInfo = methodInfo.declaringClass();

            AnnotationInstance annotation = methodInfo.annotation(GIVEN_ANNOTATION);
            if (annotation == null) {
                return;
            }
             ctx.transform()
                    .add(create(
                            CDI_NAMED_ANNOTATION,
                            annotation.target(),
                            List.of(AnnotationValue.createStringValue("value", annotation.value().toString()))))
                    .done();
        }
    }));
}
```

This didn't work either. When I try to print out the method annotations, I only see the annotation class name, no values.
When i execute this block of code:

```
Method[] method = StepDefinitions.class.getMethods();
    for (int j = 0; j < method.length; j++) {
        LOGGER.info("Method annotations: {}", method[j].getAnnotations().length);
        Annotation[] annos = method[j].getAnnotations();
        for (int i = 0; i < annos.length; i++) {
            LOGGER.info("Annotation: {}", annos[i]);
        }
    }
```

In quarkus dev mode, it prints:

- *Method annotations: 1*
- *Annotation: @io.cucumber.java.en.Given(value="today is Sunday")*

In quarkus native it prints this:

- *Method annotations: 1*
- *Annotation: @io.cucumber.java.en.Given*

At this point I have run out ideas on what to try, I am new to the quarkus ecosystem and I'm not sure if this is the right path to take or if there are better alternatives, I am open to any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so for any other people who might have the same problem as me, I found the solution while going through the chat history of https://quarkusio.zulipchat.com.
So the error I am facing is described in these Github issue comments:

https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/1983#issuecomment-483157822
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/1983#issuecomment-483686256

I removed all the changes I made to my Processor java file and just made the changes that were stated in the 1st comment.